# Painter's algorithm inside and outside test

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, projective-geometry, projection

I have read from Hearn and Baker computer graphics book. I read the test#2 painter's theorem which image is given below. [Painter's theorem of test#2 image from Hearn and Baker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Ds8.jpg)

This image showing surface S is completely behind the surface S', by checking Substitute the coordinates of all vertices of S(x, y,z) into the plane equation of S' and check for the sign. If all vertices of S are inside S' then S is behind S'. (Fig. 1).

i. e. Ax + By+ Cz + D < 0 ,x, y, z are S vertices.

But I have read from [this websites](https://www6.uniovi.es/hypgraph/scanline/visibility/painter.htm) which showing this concepts but in totally opposite manner.
See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO4o4.jpg) I read from that site, which showing opposite thing on same image. This showing
all vertices of S are outside of S'.

i. e. Ax + By+ Cz + D > 0 ,x, y, z are S vertices.

My question is how is it possible Hearn and Baker saying S is completely inside the surface S' but my mentioned website saying S is outside of S' by sign test of plane equation?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70210377/781723, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/154952/169874, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198174/82314, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4323082/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a plane is $$A x + B y + C z + D = 0 \tag{1}\label{BtV1}$$
where $(A, B, C)$ is the plane normal vector (direction perpendicular to the plane), and $-D$ is the signed distance between origin and the plane, in units of the plane normal vector length.

Note that we can multiply $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ by any nonzero real $\lambda$ (i.e., $0 \ne \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$), without affecting the plane at all.

The related equation $$A x + B y + C z + D \gt 0 \tag{2}\label{BtV2}$$ defines a [half-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)).  Essentially, the plane divides the Euclidean plane into two, and this equation is true for one of the half-spaces; specifically, the one in the direction the plane normal vector $(A, B, C)$ points to.

That choice is arbitrary.  Using $\lt$, we just choose the opposite half-space.

Sometimes, we choose the half-space the plane normal vector points to ($\gt$), and sometimes the half-space the plane normal vector points away from ($\lt$).  Both are mathematically equally valid.

If we multiply $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ in $\eqref{BtV2}$ by $-1$, all we do is replace the plane normal vector with its opposite.  To keep pointing at the same half-space, we then need to also change $\gt$ into $\lt$ and vice versa.

Thus, the difference between $\lt$ and $\gt$ in $\eqref{BtV2}$ is just a result of the free choice in choosing how the plane normal vectors are defined.  If they point away from the observer/camera, then increasing values are further away.  If they point towards the observer/camera, then decreasing values are further away.  Both are equally valid, since it is just an arbitrary choice in direction.

Comment: further away mean outside?

Comment: @Ponting: The key point is, that if you negate $A$, $B$, and $C$, you change $\gt$ into $\lt$.  The difference in the texts is that they just define the direction of vector $(A, B, C)$ in the opposite ways.  Both are equally valid, it is just a difference in convention.  (Consider, for example, the difference between left-handed and right-handed coordinate systems.  Both are equally correct, but we must choose one.  We just don't all choose the *same* one.)

Comment: If I say Ax+By+Cz+D>0 then (x, y, z) is the outside of the plane and then (−A)x+(−B)y+(−C)z+(−D)<0 indicates (x, y, z) inside of the plane ?

Comment: your statement "If they point towards the observer/camera, then decreasing values are further away."---here you take normal vector N(-A, -B, -C) ?

Comment: @Ponting: NO. $A x + B y + C z + D \gt 0$ is *mathematically equivalent to* $(-A) x + (-B) y + (-C) z + (-D) \lt 0$.  Whether that is "inside" or "outside", is a free choice.  Some choose "inside", others choose "outside".  Both are correct.  What matters is that you keep to the same choice, the same definition, throughout.  Your confusion stems from the fact that one text made one choice, and the other text the other.  That does not mean they disagree: it only means they define the direction of $(A, B, C)$ *in the opposite manner*.

Comment: I have one confusion. When normal  vector pointing away from observer then  if Ax+By+Cz+D>0 always and when normal pointing towards the observer then Ax+By+Cz+D<0 always?

Comment: Blabbo please reply.

Comment: @Ponting: I do not understand where your confusion is.  The two are equivalent.  Let statement 1 be "Normal vector $(A, B, C)$ points away from observer. We choose S when $A x + B y + C z + D \gt 0$."  Let statement 2 be "Normal vector $(A, B, C)$ points towards the observer.  We choose S when $A x + B y + C z + D \lt 0$."  My point is that statements 1 and 2 are *exactly mathematically equivalent*; that is, the same S is chosen by both statements.

Comment: understand. When normal vector pointing away from observer then Ax+By+Cz+D<0 and when normal pointing towards the observer then Ax+By+Cz+D>0 possible?

Comment: @Ponting: Yes.  The two are just different ways of saying the same thing.  The different texts are saying the same thing, they only defined the normal vector in opposite ways.  If the two texts had the exact same example or exercise, then $A, B, C, D$ in one would be $-A, -B, -C, -D$ in the other.